# Issue upgrading node.js

Tags: node.js

I tried updating node.js on both package manager [using sudo]:

```
Setting up nodejs (0.6.14-1chl1~oneiric1) ...
XXX@TPSL410:~$ node --version
v0.5.11-pre
```

And using npm

```
zain@TPSL410:~$ sudo npm install n
n@0.7.1 ./node_modules/n 
zain@TPSL410:~$ node --version
v0.5.11-pre
```

Any thoughts on why this isn't working? Thank you!

EDIT: on Ubuntu 11.04

Comment: ``echo $PATH`` and ``whereis node``

Comment: @DavidEllis thanks for your response! Do you mind being a little bit more literal as to what to do, as I'm a novice.. Thank you!

Comment: Okay, I guess you're a newbie to Linux, too? These are two commands to run in the terminal. The ``$PATH`` is a colon-delimited list of directories that programs you can run (without specifying the full path) are located. Based on your terminal output above, you probably have 3 different versions of Node.js installed (0.5.11, 0.6.14 and 0.7.1), and the output of ``whereis node`` should tell you where the 0.5.11 version is installed, so you can remove it. You probably want the 0.6.14 version since the 0.6 branch is stable and the 0.5 and 0.7 were unstable dev branches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To install a new version of node on your system, if you're having trouble, I would re-clone the node git repo into a new directory. So `cd` somewhere, perhaps just type "`cd`" to go to your home directory and then:

```
git clone https://github.com/joyent/node.git
cd node
git checkout v0.6.14
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

It's important to checkout the version you want to install with `git checkout` otherwise you'll be installing from the `master` branch which is likely unstable.

If all goes well, then try `npm --version` and you should have 0.6.14 installed.

If you want to use `n`, you should install it globally

`npm install -g n`

Then if you want to install a specific node version with `n`

`n 0.6.14`
or perhaps 
`n latest`

Then to run a node program, say it's a script called `app.js`, with one of these versions you run:

`n as 0.6.14 app.js`

Comment: Thanks, removing the directories fixed it as well. Your directions were also enlightening and appreciated.